# how to set post build event in VS to copy all satellite assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

[image: bin folder contents]

Is there a generic way I could write a post-build event in VS 2017 to copy all satellite assembly folders to another directory? Each folder contains a library named [assemblyname].resources.dll

I have 8 different configurations, all have the same set of these folders (the number of cultures will increase over time). This is why I'd prefer a generic way over hard-coding every file in the post-build macro.

PS: As I wrote this I figured out I could write a separate app to do this, but maybe still there is a way to code it inside post-build event?

Comment: the separate app would be fired from the post-build macro, with a parameter specifying which configuration was built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) command in post-build script.